# Android | Parse Json to Object without initial classes

Tags: android, json, jackson, gson

Whats the best approach to parse a JSON like this?

```
{
    "condition":{
        "text":{
            "0":"Light Rain"
        },
        "code":{
            "0":"11"
        },
        "temp":{
        "0":"8"
        },
        "date":{
        "0":"Thu, 12 Nov 2015 9:19 am EET"
        }
    },

    "forecast":{
        "Thu":{
            "day":{
                "0":"Thu"
            },
            "date":{
                "0":"12 Nov 2015"
            },
            "low":{
                "0":"5"
            },
            "high":{
                "0":"11"
            },
            "text":{
                "0":"Rain"
            },
            "code":{
                "0":"12"
            }
        },

        ...
}
```

Maybe there are some 3rd party plugins which convert JSON to Object automatically, so I dont have to create actual classes?

Everywhere I look, its advised to create a class to hold record values and then use a line like this:

```
Weather obj = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, Weather.class);
```

But in my case, this is not convenient at all.

Anyway, how would you approach a case like this? All ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is the goal you want to accomplish with the Json data?

Comment: My goal is to be able to get any value from the parsed JSON conveniently.  Similarly as a multidimensional object is formed when using `json_decode `in php.

Comment: Where are you getting this JSON from? If you are making it yourself, I'd seriously consider reformatting and flattening it. Anyways, `mapper.readTree(jsonString)` returns a `JsonNode` which is like a Map object that you get the keys out of

Comment: No, Im not making it myself, its from external source - I would surely reformat it

Comment: Still not sure I follow,. You want something more than JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJSONstring)?

Comment: Otherwise I am sure that you can (with knowledge of the format of the incomming json) create field annotated objects that can be instantiated in a similar fashion as you write in your question.

Comment: Sorry for spamming but cannot see how you would be able to automatically convert json to objects. You will have to somehow specify how the json should be interpreted.

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html